# How do I stop incrementing a number if user already tapped the correct answer?

Tags: ios, function, swift

I'm making a quiz app and I want it so that when a user taps the correct answer, their score gets incremented by one. However, if they keep tapping the same answer without proceeding to the next question, they increment their score easily.

```
 @IBAction func Button1Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        unhideLabel()
        if(correctAnswer == "1") {
            correctOrWrong.text = "Correct"
            scoreNumber++
            score.text = "Score: \(scoreNumber)"
        }
        else {
            correctOrWrong.text = "Incorrect"
            hideNextQuestion()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func Button2Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        unhideLabel()
        if (correctAnswer == "2") {
            correctOrWrong.text = "Correct"
            scoreNumber++
            score.text = "Score: \(scoreNumber)"
    }
        else {
            correctOrWrong.text = "Incorrect"
            hideNextQuestion()

        }
    }

    @IBAction func Button3Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        unhideLabel()
        if (correctAnswer == "3") {
            correctOrWrong.text = "Correct"
            scoreNumber++
            score.text = "Score: \(scoreNumber)"
    }
        else {
            correctOrWrong.text = "Incorrect"
            hideNextQuestion()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func Button4Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        unhideLabel()
        if (correctAnswer == "4") {
            correctOrWrong.text = "Correct"
            scoreNumber++
            score.text = "Score: \(scoreNumber)"
    }
        else {
            correctOrWrong.text = "Incorrect"
            hideNextQuestion()
        }
    }
}
```

What would I need to add/change if I want to stop the score from incrementing if the user already tapped the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean variable that keeps track of whether or not the question has been answered. From that, just check that before incrementing the score, and only increment the score if the boolean has not yet been set to true, and while you increment the score also set the boolean to true. That way, the score will only be increased once.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a `BOOL` property to identify  if user has selected the right answer.

Every time check it first, if has selected before. Do not add score.

```
    var hasSelected = false;

@IBAction func Button1Action(sender: AnyObject) {

    if(hasSelected){
        //Tell the user or do something you like
        return;
    }
    if(correctAnswer == "1") {
        correctOrWrong.text = "Correct"

        scoreNumber++

        score.text = "Score: \(scoreNumber)"
        //If user select the right answer
        hasSelected = true;

    }
    else {
        correctOrWrong.text = "Incorrect"
        hideNextQuestion()

    }

}
```

I think the better design is

**When user select the right one,auto come into next question**

Comment: That depends you logics, I can not figure out how you do this from the codes you post

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to write a single function instead of writing four different function with same implementation. you can use `tag` property of `UIButton` to determine the clicked button at runtime.
let's say your button1 has tag value 1 , button2 has tag value 2.... then you can write a generic action for all four button clicks..

For your problem to stop incrementing the score I'll suggest you to disable the button when user first time click on correct answer, And when next question loaded enable all buttons.

```
 @IBAction func ButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        unhideLabel()
        if ((sender as UIButton).tag == correctAnswer?.toInt()) {
           (sender as UIButton).enabled = false;
            correctOrWrong.text = "Correct"
            scoreNumber++

            score.text = "Score: \(scoreNumber)"
    }
        else {
            correctOrWrong.text = "Incorrect"
            hideNextQuestion()

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hm, it's giving me a "Could not find an overload for '==' that accepts the supplied arguments" error

Answer (score 0):

I Think the better way would be using the `UIButton` `selected` property, which is a bool. The code will go like this. And I think your are doing the same thing in all the 4 cases. So why cant you use some common method passing the answer parameters. That will simplify the code a little bit.
Sorry if I am wrong. Hope this helped you out..

```
 @IBAction func Button1Action(sender: UIButton) {
            unhideLabel()
            if(correctAnswer == "1" && sender.selected != true) {
                correctOrWrong.text = "Correct"
                scoreNumber++
                score.text = "Score: \(scoreNumber)"
                sender.selected=true
            }
            else {
                correctOrWrong.text = "Incorrect"
                hideNextQuestion()
            }
        }

        @IBAction func Button2Action(sender: UIButton) {
            unhideLabel()
            if (correctAnswer == "2" && sender.selected != true) {
                correctOrWrong.text = "Correct"
                scoreNumber++
                score.text = "Score: \(scoreNumber)"
                sender.selected=true
        }
            else {
                correctOrWrong.text = "Incorrect"
                hideNextQuestion()
            }
        }

        @IBAction func Button3Action(sender: UIButton) {
            unhideLabel()
            if (correctAnswer == "3" && sender.selected != true) {
                correctOrWrong.text = "Correct"
                scoreNumber++
                score.text = "Score: \(scoreNumber)"
                sender.selected=true
        }
            else {
                correctOrWrong.text = "Incorrect"
                hideNextQuestion()
            }
        }

        @IBAction func Button4Action(sender: UIButton) {
            unhideLabel()
            if (correctAnswer == "4" && sender.selected != true) {
                correctOrWrong.text = "Correct"
                scoreNumber++
                score.text = "Score: \(scoreNumber)"
                sender.selected=true
        }
            else {
                correctOrWrong.text = "Incorrect"
                hideNextQuestion()
            }
        }
    }
```